# Is this vulnerable to sql injection or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-injection

While looking for a solution to my problem, i found this topic:

[Rails and Arel and Scopes - simplify multiple OR's on the same table/field match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48772643/rails-and-arel-and-scopes-simplify-multiple-ors-on-the-same-table-field-match)

One of the answers is this:

```
fields = ["name", "email", "phone", "business_name", "doc_id"]
filter = fields.map { |field| "lower(#{field}) LIKE '#{term.downcase}'" }.join(' OR ')
@customers = Customer.where(filter)
```

But isn't this vulnarable to sql injections if term is a param from user input? If so, how can I make it sql injection proof? Will sanitize_sql_like fix the sql injection issue? So like this:

```
filter = fields.map { |field| "lower(#{field}) LIKE '#{sanitize_sql_like(term.downcase)}'" }.join(' OR ')
@customers = Customer.where(filter)
```

Update:
Is this a solution?

```
fields = ["name", "email", "phone", "business_name", "doc_id"]
filter = fields.map { |field| "lower(#{field}) LIKE :query" }.join(' OR ')
@customers = Customer.where(filter, query: "%#{sanitize_sql_like(term.downcase)}%")
```

Answer (score 3):

Any situation where you are interpolating user input into a SQL string is a potential SQL injection vulnerability. Escaping the input (which is what sanitize_sql_like does) can mitigate it somewhat but its always better to use bind variables to pass the user input separately to the database so that it cannot be missinterpreted as actual commands.

```
# bad
User.where("email like %#{params[:email]}%")

# good
User.where("email like ?", "%#{params[:email]}%")
```

You also do not need to manually construct that huge SQL string. Instead just create an array of ActiveRecord::Relations and join them together with the `.or` method.

```
fields = %w{ name email phone business_name doc_id }
filters = fields.map do |field|
  Customer.where("lower(#{field}) LIKE :term", term: term.downcase)
end
@customers = filters.drop(1).inject(filters.first) do |memo, scope|
  memo.or(scope)
end
```

This can look somewhat daunting but its really just a fancy pants version of:

```
Customer.where("lower(name) LIKE :term", term: term.downcase)
        .or(
          Customer.where("lower(email) LIKE :term", term: term.downcase)
        )
        .or(
          Customer.where("lower(phone) LIKE :term", term: term.downcase)
        )
        # ...
```

Comment: You can use Arel's matches method like in the linked answer but beware that it does actually interpolate the user input into the SQL query unless you pass an Arel::Nodes::BindParam or Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The first part (fields.map { |field| <query> } -> does it result to 1 db transaction or 1 transaction for each iteration?  The second part (filters.drop(1).inject(filters.first) doesn't look intuitive. If another developer wants to work on it, he or she might not understand it immediately. Does it do the same thing as filters.flatten.compact?

Comment: Yes it creates a single ActiveRecord relation and thus a single query. `flatten` and `compact` are used to flatten nested arrays and remove nils so it's in no way comparable. If you're worried about maintenance then comment the code...

Comment: `inject` is actually a looping method somewhat like each except that it yields the modified memo to each iteration of the block. It's not something which is really that alien to any experienced Ruby dev.

Comment: @max I believe you can also do it in a single block by initializing your inject/reduce with Customer.none